# Understanding type deduction for universal references

Tags: c++, function, templates, type-deduction, forwarding-reference

Let `foo` be the function:

```
template< typename T >
void foo( T&& a ){}
```

To what type will `T` be deduced for the following calls of `foo`:

```
foo( 0 ); // is T here int or int&& ?

int a = 0;
foo( a ); // is T here int or int& ?
```

Comment: You can try it by using different type traits like http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_reference or std::is_same.. and building up types with things like std::add_lvalue_reference  and then seeing what the value of the traits are

Comment: Here's an example so you can see a way to test this yourself: https://wandbox.org/permlink/51APJ9Pr4fsweWrF

Comment: Here's a trick to debug types: `template <typename T> class TD;`, then in foo, use: `TD<T>();`. As `TD` is not defined, compiler will complain, and in the error message, a good compiler will display `T`'s type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default rule for type deduction is that reference types can never be the result of deduction. Given this code,

```
template <class T>
void bar(T par);

bar(0);
int a;
bar(a);
int &b;
bar(b);
```

all 3 calls will call `foo<int>`. That is, `T` is deduced to `int` and `par` is of type `int`.

Forwarding references work by simple addition of one rule: when the argument used for type deduction of a forwarding reference (i.e. of a parameter `T&&` for a *deduced* `T`) is an lvalue of type `X`, the type `X &` is used instead of `X` for deduction.

Note that this means that given a type `X`, only `X` or `X &` can ever be the result of type deduction; `X &&` never can.

Let's analyse your code (I will rename he function parameter, to make it clear what I'm referring to):

```
template <class T>
void foo(T &&par);

foo(0);

int a;
foo(a);
```

In the first case `foo(0)`, the argument is an rvalue of type `int` The type `int` is therefore used for type deduction, meaning that `T` is deduced to `int` (the function called is `foo<int>`) and the type of `par` is `int &&`.

In the second case `foo(a)`, the argument is an *lvalue* of type `int`. Forwarding reference rule kicks in and the type `int &` is used for deduction. `T` is therefore deduced to `int &` (the function called is `foo<int&>`), and the type of `par` is "`int & &&`", which collapses to `int &`.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `T&&` in a **deduced context** like what you provided

```
template< typename T >
void foo( T&& a ){}
```

ie T is deduced based on the provided argument, is subject to
[reference collapsing rules](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers).

In short;

- if the provided argument is an **lvalue** of type `type`, `T&&`
  will expand to `type& &&` that collapses to `type&`
- if the provided argument is an **rvalue** of type `type`, `T&&`
  will expand to `type &&` that collapses to `type&&`

Note that both are **references**, if you need to trigger the rvalue
overload of another function, you need to do `std::forward<T>(a)`

Answer (score 1):

> foo( 0 ); // is T here int or int&& ?

An `int`.

> int a = 0;
>   foo( a ); // is T here int or int& ?

An `int&`.